# Fetch multiple rows combined into one row on basis of column values

Tags: postgresql

I want to fetch results from the Postgres table in such a way that all ratings are fetched according to column values in year columns.

```
table name = emp

table data:-

 eid | year | rating 
-----+------+--------
   1 | 2018 | \A
   2 | 2018 | \B
   3 | 2018 | \A
   1 | 2019 | \B
   2 | 2019 | \B
   3 | 2019 | \C
   1 | 2020 | \A
   2 | 2020 | \A
   3 | 2020 | \A
```

I want to fetch result following form:-

```
 eid | 2018 | 2019 | 2020
 ----+------+------+------
 1   |   \A | \B   | \A
 2   |   \B | \B   | \A
 3   |   \A | \C   | \A
```

If this can be done without cte than it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `crosstab()` to achieve this. The `crosstab` function is part of a PostgreSQL extension called `tablefunc`. To call the `crosstab` function, you must first enable the `tablefunc` extension by executing the following SQL command:

```
CREATE extension tablefunc;
```

Now you need to execute the following query to achieve the expected result:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab( 'select eid, year, rating from emp order by 1,2') AS final_result(eid numeric, "2018" TEXT,"2019" TEXT,"2020" TEXT);
```

Please note that this will work only if you have only the 3 values `2018`, `2019` and `2020` in year column.